# How to disable TeamCity polling

Tags: teamcity

By default TeamCity polls the repo at specific interval, but I have a git hook to fire the build, how to disable the polling?

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings for your VCS root, and click on "Show advanced options". There is a setting called "Checking interval". I think setting it to 0 would disable the polling.

EDIT: It seems that the only way is to set it to a very high number instead. For instance 90000000 seconds is almost 3 years. I guess that is close to "disabled" in the digital era. :-)